# Is it necessary to upgrade my groupset?

Tags: groupsets

Just arrived here!
I have a bike (Venzo Traveler) very similar (almost identical) to a Trek 920.
27v with a RD Acera (11-36) and an Altus FD (22-32-40).
No dropbars, just bullhorn. Very light and with 700x38 tires.
Right now commuting with it but training for crossing the Andes next year. As you can see, will use it in a mountain setting but mainly on asphalt and some gravel.
I've been thinking about upgrading the groupset. Some have told me about upgrading to a Sora 2x9 or going mono but sincerely know nothing about this new Shimano products.
Any advice?
Thanks

Comment: Necessary for what? More expensive groupsets usually give you lower weight, more functionality (mostly more gears) and more quality (though midrange products already have solid quality).

Comment: That's it! Thanks! I've been thinking if it is necessary to upgrade before the trip to the Andes.

Comment: A 22:36 low ratio is going to be great for steep climbs.  What more are you wanting to achieve?  Do not go "mono" or single gear, that's a trendy hipster idea for the flats, not challenging climbs.

Comment: @Criggie I think that maybe "mono" might refer to using a single chainring for a 1x set up instead of converting to a single speed or fixed gear set up

Comment: @GageMartin imho, 1x is also a trendy hipster idea for the flats or low slopes; 3x/2x give you a nice full range of ratios,

Comment: IMO 22/36 is too low  for almost anything, but that doesn't matter.  My MTB's lowest is 22/34 and is more useful for lifting the front wheel or spinning the back wheel than climbing

Comment: @Armand At the cost of everything that a >1x entails.

Comment: @Chris H That’s a significantly harder low gear than what can be found on modern MTBs (30t chainring, between 50 to 52t large cog.) The symptoms you describe relate to geometry and tire choices respectively.

Comment: Thanks guys! Very useful information!

Comment: @MaplePanda I'm rather constrained on tyre choice at the back by the clearance to the FD (cheap hardtail, But it's adequate for what I do). Combined with slippery mud common round here that means shifting my weight can only help so much. It's not that I never use it, just rarely, and for short bursts. The question wasn't about a mountain though bike, but a gravel bike/off-road tourer.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you have is more ideal for steep climbs you would find in the mountains than most up-market groupsets. As @Criggie has pointed out, 22:36 is ideal for climbs. Going to a more expensive groupset will most likely give you worse gearing unless you choose something that is specific to climbing.

A standard Sora groupset will come with a 50-34 chainset and an 11-32 cassette, which won't be great for touring especially if you are carrying a load. Some mono (1x) groupsets can get a 50t cog in the back, but to get the same ratio as your 22:36 you would need a 31 tooth chainring which is pretty small and would end up giving you a much easier hard gear. Assuming the smallest cog of 11 teeth, you would only be going at 33 km/h at 90 RPM in your hardest gear.

If you want an upgrade to get better quality components you are better off going with something from the Deore line like a mountain double with something like 36/22t chainrings or a mountain triple with 40/30/22t chainrings

Comment: If they're going for Sora, get the triple, with 50/39/30.  With that and 11-32 I've ground my way up 16% paved slopes carrying 35kg of luggage

Comment: A 9-52 cassette would do the trick, but I agree that a multiple chainring setup would be better here.

Comment: @MaplePanda Wasn't even aware you could get a 9-52. I looked it up and it's about $250, not to mention you'd probably need some special freehub to accommodate it. Even then, you would only be able to have a 32 tooth chainring to get the same gear ratio as 22:36, and you would still top out at around 42 km/h at 90 RPM. probably fast enough for touring, but still seems like not a great solution.